# label input inline-block переносится на следующую строку при нехватке места

Tags: css, inline

Нужно, что бы элемент не переносился на другую строку при нехватке места и не залазил влево на предыдущий... (а были строго в ряд)
width у label не указан, input должен быть растянут на всю оставшуюся(доступную) длинну от label.

```css
.input-w {
  width: 332px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-w label {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-w input {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: olive;
}

input {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-w">
  <label for="#your-input">Your label</label>
  <input type="text" id="your-input" />
</div>
```

float не помогает

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `Flexbox`:

```css
.input-w {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.input-w label {
  padding-right: .5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input-w input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-w">
  <label for="#your-input">Your label</label>
  <input type="text" id="your-input" />
</div>
```

Вариант с `display: table`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-w {
  display: table-row;
}

.input-w label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}

.input-w input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input-w">
    <label for="#your-input">Your label</label>
    <input type="text" id="your-input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! такой вариант работает. Только вот вторая ячейка строится столбцом, вместо того, что бы быть четко за концом длинны 1й. И за границы указанной длинны вылазит содержимое, overflow:hidden почему то не  работает...

Comment: @CodeGust, обновил ответ на счет 2-й ячейки быть за концом 1-й.
Какому элементу вы задаете ширину и вылазит содержимое?

Comment: в том и сложность, что у каждой label свои слова, т. е. длинна и задать фиксированный width нельзя.
а вот еще заметил, если  overflow:hidden для контейнера поставить, тогда прыгает влево, пряча labels и показывая оставшуюся длинну input

Comment: @CodeGust, на счет `overflow: hidden`, вы наверное добавили паддинг для label. Попробуйте инпуту добавить `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: @CodeGust, а на счет разной ширины лаблов: красивее когда инпут поля одной ширины, соответственно ширина лаблов будет фиксированной по ширине самой большей.

Comment: border-box - был.

Comment: длаю пиксельвпиксель верстку, так что должен как есть верстать...

Comment: @CodeGust, можно задать ширину лаблов `width: 1px;`.